# MS Access 2003 Field Value []

Tags: ms-access-2003

One of the fields in the MS Access Form has the value as `=[OpenThisMonth]+[ClosedThisMonth]` in the Design View. I tried figuring out what these values stand for. It is not a database field. It is not present in the form itself as any other field. It is not a macro too. I do not understand the syntax either. Does anyone know what it might represent.

If I click on the control source of the field. I get this - [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LGFJuG5kGBVzJqbHZ6WFd0b0U/edit?usp=sharing)

EDIT

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW clients.*,
                   businesscodes.businesstype,
                   firstname + "" + lastname AS HContact,
                   brokers.brokername,
                   brokers.contact
FROM   ((clients
         LEFT JOIN businesscodes
                ON clients.businesscode = businesscodes.businesscode)
        LEFT JOIN hamiltoncontacts
               ON clients.hamiltoncontact = hamiltoncontacts.hamiltoncontact)
       LEFT JOIN brokers
              ON clients.brokernumber = brokers.brokernumber
ORDER  BY clients.clientname;
```

Comment: Is the form based off a table or a query?  Those could be calculated fields in a query.

Comment: It is based on a query `SELECT DISTINCTROW Clients.*
 , BusinessCodes.BusinessType
 , FirstName+" "+LastName AS HContact
 , Brokers.BrokerName
 , Brokers.Contact
FROM ((Clients LEFT JOIN 
  BusinessCodes 
   ON Clients.BusinessCode = BusinessCodes.BusinessCode) 
  LEFT JOIN HamiltonContacts 
   ON Clients.HamiltonContact = HamiltonContacts.HamiltonContact) 
 LEFT JOIN Brokers 
  ON Clients.BrokerNumber = Brokers.BrokerNumber
ORDER BY Clients.ClientName;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here --

There was a subform which had fields by the name OpenThisMonth and ClosedThisMonth